# C++ static variable in member function

Tags: c++, object, static

So for code like this:

```
class foo{
  void bar(){
     static int var = 2;
  }
};
```

I know that there will only be on instance of `var` for all objects of type `foo` but does C++ allocate memory for variable `var` even before foo is created? I ask this because even after `foo` has been destroyed, var will exist throughout the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does C++ allocate memory for variable `var` even before foo is created?

Yes, it does, in the sense that the memory the value of `var` will eventually occupy is reserved upfront. When the constant value of `2` is written into `var`'s memory is implementation-defined. The only thing the standard guarantees is that it is going to happen at some point before you call `foo::bar()`.

If you initialize your static variable using an expression with side effects (say, by making a function call) this call will be performed the first time that you execute the function.

> after foo has been destroyed, var will exist throughout the program.

`var` will exist independently of any instances of `foo` that your program may create. When you call `foo::bar()` at any time, you would get the last value of `var` that your program has assigned to it.

Comment: *before* the first call to `foo::bar()`?  What if the initial value had side-effects? (allowed in C++, not in C)  Do those side effects occur at an unpredictable time?

Comment: Memory allocation is not initialization.  *Initialization* (of the previously allocated memory area) will happen exactly the first time the function is called.  It should be noted that the memory will be allocated statically at program startup, not using `malloc` or the like.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, these pesky side effects! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`var` will be *constructed* the first time foo:bar() is called.  It will be destructed when the program terminates.

Note that `foo` is a class, not an object instance, hence `foo` is never "destroyed"

UPDATE: The standard says that that the storage for the variable is allocated when the program begins. [en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) –  (Thanks to broncoAbierto for correcting me).

Comment: `foo` is never “destroyed” but its static members *are* as part of the program de-initialization.  For an `int`, this is of course a no-op.

Comment: @5gon12eder: yes, but the OP referred to the destruction of foo as something happening before shutdown.

Comment: The standard says that that the storage for the variable is allocated when the program begins. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: @broncoAbierto:  That's why I hedged on it.  Thanks.  I'll update it.

Comment: @broncoAbierto: That website says it.  But what does the standard say?

Comment: I assumed they had taken it from the standard. Maybe they haven't.